# @GetMapping UTF-8 encoding not working properly - Croatian

Tags: spring-boot, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, request-mapping

I'm having problems with getting response in correct encoding, And I've tried everything I found on net.

MySQL database is in utf8mb4_croatian_ci collation.

Example of database records:

```
Abadžić Stanko
Ač Nataša
Adamović Dubravko
Adrić Marija
Here is my controller:
```

This is my rest controller:

```
@RestController
public class AutorController {

    @Autowired
    private AutorService autorService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/autori",  produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    public List<Autor> getAllAutors() {
        return autorService.getAllAutors();
    }
}
```

application.properties where I tried to configure encoding for tomcat:

```
server.tomcat.uri-encoding = UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true 
spring.http.encoding.force=true
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=UTF-8
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.tomcat.connection-properties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;
```

This is the response I get:

```
    "id": 2,
        "imeAutora": "AbadÅ¾iÄ‡ Stanko"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "imeAutora": "AÄ� NataÅ¡a"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "imeAutora": "AdamoviÄ‡ Dubravko"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "imeAutora": "AdriÄ‡ Marija"
    }
```

P.S. Also when I change encoding in controller into ISO-8859-2 (also should support Croatian language):

```
@GetMapping(value = "/autori",  produces = "application/json;charset=ISO-8859-2")
```

my response is like:

```
 "id": 2,
        "imeAutora": "AbadĂ…ÂžiĂ„â€Ą Stanko"
```

which means that setting charset in @GetMapping is doing something , but it's doing it wrong

If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: Are you sure you are viewing the result file as UTF-8?

Comment: Giacomo Catenazzi, how do you mean?
I get the same result in browser and in postman...

Comment: Check which encoding is using your browser in that specific page. Maybe you could check the headers, if webserver (reverse proxy) changed values. In any case, it is your task to see in which (of the many steps and conversion) the character start to be wrong, then you may ask a more specific question. There are so many steps, that we can just guess, we lack most of the data.